# correct usage of "you and I/me"

Tags: coordination, personal-pronouns, case

I read from a book that "you and I" replaces "we" in a sentence, while "you and me" replaces "us".

Examples:

> 1. The professor wants to see you and me [us].
> 2. You and I [we] will go together.

Is this correct?

I was under the notion that "I" and "me" could be used interchangeably.

Comment: Even when both *I* and *me* can be used, I wouldn't call them interchangeable—there's often a difference of register.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with subject and objects in a sentence.

```
I see you
```

`I` is the subject and `you` is the object.

```
You see me
```

`You` is the subject and `me` is the object.

Subject pronouns - the one performing the action:

- I
- She
- He
- We

Object pronouns - the one receiving the action:

- Me
- Her
- Him
- Us

Answer (score 1):

Those sentences are correct.

*I* is used when the speaker is the agent of the verb.

> I see the dog.
>
> I am happy.

*me* is used when the speaker is the patient of the verb.

> The dog sees me.
>
> She gave me the book.

Edit:

As snailplane said in the comments, you would still use *I* when you make a passive sentence (you don't know or say who or what is doing the action).

> I am being watched. (The dog is watching me.)
>
> I was given the book. (She gave me the book.)

Comment: The forms are actually more closely aligned with syntactic roles than semantic.  Consider passives: "I was given the book", not \*"Me was given the book."

Comment: @snailplane True.

Comment: I rolled back the edit.  I don't think we should edit additional errors into other people's answers.

Comment: @snailboat Though I did misspell "sentence".  It doesn't help that in my dialect, it is pronounced /sɪntæns/.

Comment: The spelling isn't important to me and I wasn't trying to point it out.  I was referring to what I wrote in my first comment: *I* and *me* correspond to syntactic roles rather than semantic.